# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message' (Discord Bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

For some reason send_message isn't working properly on my Discord bot and I can't find anyway to fix it.

```
import asyncio
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.async_event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
   if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        print('on_message !test')
        await test(author, message)
async def test(author, message):
    print('in test function')
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hi %s, i heard you.' % author)
client.run("key")
```

```
on_message !test
in test function
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\indit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 223, in _run_event
    yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 15, in on_message
    await test(author, message)
  File "bot.py", line 21, in test
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Hi %s, i heard you.' % author)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Comment: Are you on async or rewrite branch?

Comment: After correcting bad indentation and using my own token it worked just fine on my Linux machine.

Answer (score 16):

You are probably running the rewrite version of discord.py, since the `discord.Client` object does not a have a `send_message` method.

To fix your problem you can just have it as:

```
async def test(author, message):
    await message.channel.send('I heard you! {0.name}'.format(author))
```

but for what i see you doing I reccomend using the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/index.html)

This makes creating a bot and commands for the bot much simpler, for example here is some code that does exactly the same as yours

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('I heard you! {0}'.format(ctx.author))

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: For some reason if you want to install the rewrite version use this python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/rewrite.zip

Comment: Actually its better to use this command `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]`

Comment: Now that rewrite (v1.0.0) has officially been released this version **should** now be installed through a simple `pip install discord.py`

Answer (score 1):

As per `discord.py` documentation, migration to v1.0 brought a lot of major changes in the API, including the fact that a lot of functionality was **moved out of `discord.Client` and put into their respective model**.

E.g. in your specific case:
`Client.send_message(abc.Messageable)` --> `abc.Messageable.send()`

So your code would be restyled from this:

```
await client.send_message(message.channel, 'I heard you! {0}'.format(message.author))
```

to this:

```
await message.channel.send('I heard you! {0}'.format(message.author))
```

This makes the code much more consistent and more accurate in depicting the actual discord entities, i.e. it's intuitive that a discord `Message` is sent to a `Channel` (subclass of `abc.Messageable`) and not to the `Client` itself.

There is a quite large list of migrations in this sense; you can find them all [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html)
under the *`Models are Stateful`* section.

Answer (score 0):

The discord.py can't be used for the `send_message()` function anymore, I think. But this doesn't mean we can not send messages. Another way of sending messages into the channel do exist.

You can use:

```
await message.channel.send("")
```

for this purpose.

So let's apply this into your code now.

```
import asyncio
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.async_event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
   if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        print('on_message !test')
        await test(author, message)
async def test(author, message):
    print('in test function')
    await message.channel.send(F'Hi {author}, I heard you.')

client.run("key")
```

Now this would fix your issue and you'll be able to use your bot to send messages easily.

Thank You! :D