# How to fix "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'" with Beautiful Soup 4 scraping HTML url

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to scrape HTML from a URL and have my discord bot display the results. Friend provided the code and it was tested. However, I believe he was using an older version of discord.py. He is currently unavailable. I have searched for the proper changes needed, but haven't found them specific to my problem.

I have tried changing the `client.send_message` to `channel.send` - I get another error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

```py
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

channel = client.get_channel('CHANNEL ID')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!dfx2'):
        website_url = requests.get('http://novaworld.cc/dfx2lobby.php?lob=pub').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table')
        test = table.select_one('tr:contains("!GET SOME")')
        text = test.get_text()
        print(text)
        await channel.send(message.channel, content = text)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' after changing `client.send_message`

Comment: Your channel assignment happens before the client has started so it will always be None. Move the assignment into the `on_message` function instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send\_message' (Discord Bot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116872/attributeerror-client-object-has-no-attribute-send-message-discord-bot)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never used bs4, but I'll try to help. To get channel you have to use

```
channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, id=message.channel.id)
```

Then **if you use newer version** of discord.py (rewrite) just send this message by using

```
await channel.send(text)
```

Comment: That `get` call is looking for a channel with the same id as the guild it belongs to, which can't happen as ids are unique.

Comment: You are right... I edited it to `message.channel.id`.

Comment: Why not just use `message.channel` directly?  `await message.channel.send(text)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need message.channel inside your channel.send. I'd use this:

```
channel = message.channel
await channel.send(content = text)
```

Let me know how this works :)