# discord.py 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Tags: python, discord, scheduled-tasks, bots, discord.py

My python script ends with the following lines:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<time_check() done, defined at rewards.py:18> exception=AttributeError("'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rewards.py", line 25, in time_check
    await client.send_message(channel, messages)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

I don`t know why this error is appearing. Can someone help me to fix it ?

I have changed **client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')** to **client = discord.Client()** but the Error seems to be the same.

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<time_check() done, defined at rewards.py:19> exception=AttributeError("'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rewards.py", line 26, in time_check
    await client.send_message(channel, messages)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Here is the python bot that I use. they should post a message to a specific time.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'NzQ4ODc1MXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXRKO4ORH0'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

alarm_time = '15:25'
channel_id = '748XXXXXXXXXX5'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Online.')


async def time_check():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        messages = ('Test')
        if now == alarm_time:
           await client.send_message(channel, messages)
           time = 90
        else:
           time = 1
        await asyncio.sleep(time)


client.loop.create_task(time_check())

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116872/attributeerror-client-object-has-no-attribute-send-message-discord-bot

Answer (score 0):

Replace `await channel.send_message(messages)` instead of `await client.send_message(channel, messages)` if that doesn't works, try `await channel.send(messages)`. That will work for you.

Comment: await channel.send_message(messages) bring the following error, too. 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Comment: change the `channel_id` variable's value as an real channel id.

Comment: Same Error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Are you sure that `channel_id` has a real channel's?

Comment: And has bot the required permission to see that channel?

Comment: yep. the bot has joined the channel an has all permission

Comment: Can you also try to replace `client.get_channel(id=channel_id).send('test')`

Comment: same error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
mhhh i dont know

Comment: I'm confused sorry, I can't help you.