# Python Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
channel = bot.get_channel(id_here)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("It's ready")
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        if channel:
            await bot.send_message(channel, 'hi')
            print("successfully sent message")

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

My goal is to have the discord bot repeat itself every 5 seconds in my specific channel, though it's not working. I am getting this error

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python\price.py", line 25, in on_ready
    await bot.send_message(channel, 'hi')
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Comment: What do you not understand about the Discord examples and the error message?  `send_message` is not a method of class `Bot`.

Comment: I am looking for the correct syntax

Comment: Well, you wrote old syntax in new rewrite version of discord.py. Please refer to discord.py's docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send\_message' (Discord Bot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116872/attributeerror-client-object-has-no-attribute-send-message-discord-bot)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this:

```py
if channel await bot.send_message(channel, 'hi'):
    print("successfully sent message")
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop copying code from old docs/answers. Use `await channel.send("Hi")`

Answer (score 0):

Please do not do anything in your `on_ready`, discord has a tendency of completely disconnecting you from their service (error code 1000, 1006) when doing something tedious in the `on_ready`.

**Make use of the `discord.ext.tasks` helper package!**
Make use of the [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/) for `.ext.tasks`, it is extremely important.

A quick code snippet for your question:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

# your bot initialization here

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def _send_msg():
    if not bot.is_ready(): return #wait until bot is fully ready

    ch = bot.get_channel(...)
    await ch.send(...)

#before running your bot:
_send_msg.start()
```