# Client.send_message is not working anymore so is there another way?

Tags: python, discord.py

In this code I am trying to make the bot send a message when the user reacts through an emoji but   `Client.send_message` function is not working for me, it throws an error saying that `'client' object has no attribute 'send message'` So, is there any other way to send messages?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.Client()





@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('ready')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  channel = reaction.message.channel

  await client.send_message(channel, '{} has reacted by using {} emoji, his message was ()'.format(user.name, reaction.emoji, reaction.message.content))
  await client.process_commands(reaction.message)


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: you should define client with either Bot or Client class, not both, and also, you should've to do like `message.channel.send('{} has reacted by using {} emoji, his message was ()'.format(user.name, reaction.emoji, reaction.message.content)))`

Comment: I removed the client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') but still it gave me the same error and if I put message.channel,send it will say that message is not defined

Comment: try `channel.send(....)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send\_message' (Discord Bot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116872/attributeerror-client-object-has-no-attribute-send-message-discord-bot)

Comment: I solved the problem all i had to do was use the f string formatting method and now its works thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest `Discord.py` version (`1.7.3`), you can use the [`.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) method, like this:

```
ctx.channel.send("Hey")
ctx.message.send("Hey")
ctx.send("Hey")
```

---

This code should work:

```
await channel.send(f'{user.name} has reacted by using {reaction.emoji} emoji, his message was {reaction.message.content}')
```

Remember that in Python `3.6+` you should use the [`f-string`](https://blog.finxter.com/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-formatted-string-literal/#:%7E:text=Summary%3A%20f%2Dstring%20is%20more,for%20Python%202.6%20and%20above.) formatting method.

Comment: It throws me another error saying that "'TextChannel' has no attribute 'send'"

Comment: You should check your Discord.py version, writing in your command prompt "py -m pip list"

Comment: My version is 1.7.3 is that the correct one i should have?

Comment: thanks a lot it worked i forgot to use the f-string formatting method!

Answer (score 0):

This shoud work:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('ready')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  channel = reaction.message.channel

  await channel.send('{} has reacted by using {} emoji, his message was ()'.format(user.name, reaction.emoji, reaction.message.content))
  await client.process_commands(reaction.message)


client.run('TOKEN')
```

What this does is called the `send` function directly through the channel. This works in `Discord.py` version `1.7.3`

Comment: It throws me another error saying that "'TextChannel' has no attribute 'send'"

Comment: Now it worked what this code lacked is the f string formatting method, after i added that my code works like wine thank you so much for helping me